# linux (general) file/directory rename/delete operations under os permission scheme

Tags: files, permissions, directory

In linux, do file/directory rename/delete operations belong to write permission?

Comment: Yes. To rename, delete or create a file, you have to be able to write to its parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

the permission to move/rename a dir, comes from the permission of the ".." dir (containing dir), not from the dir itself.

Simple testcase

`$ mkdir testdir/subdir -p
$ chmod -w testdir
$ mv testdir/subdir testdir/othersub`

mv: das Verschieben von »testdir/subdir“ nach »testdir/othersub“ ist nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung  ==> no permission